# How HAProxy manages certificates on ip address?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy

I have a ha-proxy with multiple ssl certificates. all certificates stored in /etc/ssl directory. every thing works well but when I use ip address of server (in web browser) it matches the first ssl certificate and shows the first domain name (for example abc.com).

```
frontend Frontend
    bind    *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/
    mode    http
```

I have created a pem file (with aaa.com.pem name) so it doesn't show domain name but I need a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

HAProxy allows multiple `crt` bind options, and will use the first certificate it loads as the default.  So if you want to specify a default if no SNI matches you can do something like [this](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/master/examples/ssl.cfg#L17):

```
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/default.pem crt /etc/ssl/certdir/
```